# Creating a C# Windows background app service

Tags: c#, windows, cortana

I wonder how I can "set the background task to AppService".

I tried to create a Windows 10 application for Cortana and I follow these steps: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn974228.aspx

I somehow can't figure out what I need to do here, because I don't have the appxmanifest file:

**In Visual Studio, open your app and declare the background task as an AppService in the app manifest.**

I know that sounds weird, but I could really not seek out. Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: But it tells you the steps right after that line, [from `a.` to `h.`](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4L3s2.png), eight of them.

Answer (score 2):

1. Double click Package.appxmanifest
2. -> Declarations
3. Select `Background Tasks`
4. Click <kbd>Add</kbd>
5. Click the `More Info` link for more information

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I don't have those files (appxmanifest). I think I created the wrong project? Screenshot edited.

Comment: I'm fairly certain you must add a background task to a Universal Windows Application. It runs the background task when the app is suspended. If you create a Universal Windows Platform app, you will have the *.appxmanifest file in which you may link to your class library.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, it looks like you skipped a step, and only created a solution with a Runtime Component project in it, but the background task is intended to be added to an existing universal windows app.

If you're looking to create an app that also implements a background task that can run inside Cortana, you'll want to do the following:

1. Create a new blank app of the Universal Windows type ( eg, c# -> Windows -> Universal -> Blank app from the new project window).
2. Inside that solution, go to file -> New -> Project and create a new Windows Runtime Component (you've already performed that step above)
3. From the blank app project, you'll install your Voice Command Definition (VCD) file (as per the documentation linked in your question), update the package manifest, etc.
4. From the Windows Runtime Component project, you'll implement the code that will run in Cortana's background task when invoked by a voice command.
5. From the blank app project, add a reference to the runtime component to ensure that both projects are deployed when you run the app from VS/install it.

I'll agree that the steps in the documentation aren't completely clear, they mention it as a prerequisite but it's not explicit enough. I'll pass that along to the MSDN documentation team. The reason you need two separate projects (for C# and C++/CX projects anyway) is because you'll still need an existing app to install the VCD file into Cortana, and it can be launched by Cortana depending on some of the outcomes of the background task.

The documentation that the MSDN article you link is based on the sample code here: [Cortana Voice Command](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/CortanaVoiceCommand) in Microsoft's sample github repository which should help demonstrate how to connect the projects together.

Comment: Please explain your answer and not just link to an external site

Comment: I thought I had explained the answer, but sure, I'll expand it to be more clear. The site I linked to is the sample code that the original question's MSDN link is based on, btw. I'll make that more clear as well.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Just wanted to give a tip on how to craft a good SO answer since it was your first post :)

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Brevity isn't an ideal trait here.